# Serialization Assembly. Is it needed or not?

Tags: c#, web-services, serialization, assemblies, clickonce

I have a .net 2.0 c# ClickOnce app and it connects to its data via Web Services.  I've been told that one way to potentially speed up the application is to generate a serialization assembly beforehand. I have several questions on this front.

1. The default setting to whether to generate a serialization assembly is Auto.  What criteria does VS2005 use to decide whether to generate a serialization assembly or not?  It seems like it does not generate under Debug configuration, but it does under Release configuration, but I can't tell for sure and can't the information anywhere.
2. Does serialization assembly actually improve the startup of the application?  Specifically what does it improve?  Do I actually need a serialization assembly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is really asking "Shall I pre-generate the serialization assemblies and include it in the deployed project or shall I fall back on the default of generating the assemblies on the fly?" Generally that won't hurt too much after the first hit perf-wise. Where it can play in is that the serialization assemblies are generated in `%SYSTEMROOT%\TEMP`. Which, in some cases, the process can't access, leading to fatal exceptions in most cases.

Answer (score 6):

This is not relevant to your situation, but there's another good reason for pre-generating the serialization assembly - it's necessary when hosting your code in SQL Server (i.e. SQLCLR). SQL Server doesn't allow these assemblies to be generated dynamically, so your serialization code would fail inside SQL Server.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases, you aren't likely to see a huge benefit from this, especially if you keep the app open for a while. Pre-generating a serialization assembly mainly helps the *first* time (in an exe lifetime) that you serialize a specific type as xml.

Answer (score 2):

According to Intellitrace, only the first time you XML-serialize a type, a FileNotFoundException is thrown and then caught. This means CLR expects to load an assembly containing all the XML-Serializers for that specific Assembly and when it's not found, a FileNotFoundException is thrown to signal the XmlSerializer: "Hey! Generate the darn assembly!" and this is what happens during that "Catch" and then the previously not found file exists.

I've read somewhere that using try-catch for logic is a bad exercise. IDK why Microsoft has used this approach...