# .net windows form webservice call SLOW/ Startup delay

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have a windows form application that I've recently been handed to upgrade.  It makes two Web Services calls (using .net Web References functionality). One is SSL, the other is not.

The first webservice requested after you open the client takes about 12 seconds, any other requests take about .5 sec.  -Regardless of which webservice you request first, and any future request is fast regardless of which until you close the client.
After you open the client again the first hit takes a 12 seconds again.

I've having a hard time searching for this because of the huge amount of forum posts regarding the *Server* first load that occurs with IIS metadata.  I'm familiar with that issue and it is not what is occurring here.

Also, the database calls that the application performs have no such delay.  I'm not leaning towards a network issue because of that.

Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: have you read through this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926919/serialization-assembly-is-it-needed-or-not - sounds like it is this or similar.

Comment: So I set Generate Serialization assembly to ON on all three projects in this app.  The BIN/Release folder contains only one .XmlSerializers.dll file.  Is that expected.  Also this doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A delay that long is probably I/O related, either disk (generating XML serializers) or network (DNS resolution, certificates, strong name validation, etc.).  Check the resource monitor: is the CPU, disk, or network loaded?  If not, it's probably a network call stuck on a timeout.

Try capturing data with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), which will include all disk and network traffic.

If the problem looks to be network-related, then [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) might give a clearer picture.

Comment: I was hoping not to have to go down that path on a Friday.  :-)  I'll see what it returns.